# Export Oracle table using Stored Procedure to an excel file

Tags: oracle, export-to-excel

I am using SQL Developer 1.5.5 and I need to export some tables from an Oracle 11g database to an xls file. I have tried using spool, but I cannot put in a stored procedure as error comes up. Is there some other alternative to do this?

I am trying to create reports from data base by executing the procedure.

Thanks.

Comment: You can use the UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE procedure for that. Example: https://community.oracle.com/thread/1049319?tstart=0

Comment: Thanks Nitish. Let me try this! :D

Comment: I tried this and created a procedure. The procedure got compiled without any issues, but while running the procedure, the file was not getting created. I am trying to create the file in a shared path, and running the script logged on a remote machine (for which I am not an admin) :/
Can you advise me on this?

Answer (score 0):

Anton Scheffer (from AMIS.NL) wrote an APEX plugin to load Oracle data into a Excel file. It works very well and it can be used alone (without APEX) with a additional work.

Check out: http://technology.amis.nl/2011/02/19/create-an-excel-file-with-plsql/

You can also use SQLX (see http://technology.amis.nl/2006/01/20/generate-anative-excel-file-with-sqlx/) but it could be very complex depending on what you ha